# Using ELSEIF & SWITCH/FUNCTION on MATLAB, Convert Age to Characters

Tags: matlab

I've been home alone and have been learning some MATLAB. I want to create a script in which:

- asks a user to enter an age in years as a number between 20 and 59 (inclusive):
- checks that the given age is in the range, if the value is outside the range the program should exit with printing out the error message.
- if the age is in the range the program should convert the values to a text equivalent (i.e. 21 to ”twenty-one”)

So far, I've tried to split the Age into tens and units to get the prefix and suffix of each number by using fix(Age/10) and mod(Age,10). I've got the main body of it, it's almost there however I cannot seem to get the output I want. Could someone help me fiddle this, please? Thanks

```
Age=input('How old are you? ')
if Age<20 
disp('You are too young ')

elseif Age>=20 & Age<=59
    fix(Age/10); 
    mod(Age,10);
switch fix(Age/10)
    case fix(Age/10)==2
           disp('twenty')
    case fix(Age/10)==3
           disp('thirty')
    case fix(Age/10)==4
           disp('forty')  
    case fix(Age/10)==5
           disp('fifty')
    otherwise
     end
switch mod(Age,10)
    case mod(Age,10)==1
         disp('-one')
    case mod(Age,10)==2
         disp('-two')  
    case mod(Age,10)==3
         disp('-three')
    case mod(Age,10)==4
         disp('-four')
    case mod(Age,10)==5
         disp('-five')
    case mod(Age,10)==6
         disp('-six')
    case mod(Age,10)==7
         disp('-seven')
    case mod(Age,10)==8
         disp('-eight')
    case mod(Age,10)==9
         disp('-nine')
    otherwise
      end
    elseif Age>59
    disp('You are too old ')
end
```

Comment: You are almost there. You don't need to put the condition again with case numbers. e.g.

`case fix(Age/10)==2` should be just `case 2`.  
and   
`case mod(Age,10)==1` should be just  `case 1`.

Same goes for the rest of your cases. Please see the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html)

Comment: Another thing: `elseif Age>=20 & Age<=59` can be simply `elseif Age<=59`. If you get to this `else`, you've already established that `Age<20` is not true, there's no need to test for it again. The same is true for the last `elseif`, if can be a plain `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
Age=input('How old are you? ')
if Age<20 
    disp('You are too young ')
elseif Age>=20 & Age<=59
    switch fix(Age/10)
        case 2
               fprintf('twenty')
        case 3
               fprintf('thirty')
        case 4
               fprintf('forty')  
        case 5
               fprintf('fifty')
        otherwise
         end
    switch mod(Age,10)
        case 1
             fprintf('-one')
        case 2
             fprintf('-two')  
        case 3
             fprintf('-three')
        case 4
             fprintf('-four')
        case 5
             fprintf('-five')
        case 6
             fprintf('-six')
        case 7
             fprintf('-seven')
        case 8
             fprintf('-eight')
        case 9
             fprintf('-nine')
        otherwise
          end
elseif Age>59
    disp('You are too old ')
end
```

For Switch statements, in each case, you just need to enter the value that the expression by the switch keyword should be matched to.

Also, use fprintf instead of disp to show the two words on the same line i.e.

> thirty-four

instead of

> thirty
>   -four

This is because `disp` automatically formats each output onto a new line whilst `fprintf` does not and gives more control over the output.